# How to open the command line in Chrubuntu?

Tags: command-line, chromebook, chrubuntu

I would like just in case I need to make Chrome the default again, to open a terminal window.

- Where is the terminal applications located in Chrubuntu?
- Is there any key-shortcut that allows me to directly prompt for terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrubuntu is a linux distribution based on Ubuntu that runs on chromebooks. So, it should be the same like in Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. See more at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **ctrl-alt-t**? Opens a terminal on every *buntu I've used for as long as I've used it.